# Python argparse list all possible commands for a defined parser

Tags: python, argparse, command-line-arguments

Is there a way of listing or generating all possible combinations of valid commands that can be executed for a parser defined using argparse? 
If it's not possible with argparse, does anyone know any other parser that has this functionality?

E.g. If I have a parser defined:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='myProg', usage='%(prog)s [options]')
parser.add_argument('--foo1', help='foo help')
parser.add_argument('--foo2', help='foo help')
```

Is there a command/package that can take this parser and generate all possible combinations of commands:

```
myProg --foo1 test --foo2 test
myProg --foo1 test
myProg --foo2 test
```

Comment: What's an example of specifically what you're looking for?

Comment: Can you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

With your `parser` I get:

```
In [34]: parser.print_usage()
usage: myProg [options]
```

That's because you specified: `usage='%(prog)s [options]'`.  Removing that gives me:

```
In [38]: parser.print_usage()
usage: myProg [-h] [--foo1 FOO1] [--foo2 FOO2]
```

Based on the info in that line I could list possible inputs

```
myProg -h
myProg --foo1 FOO1
myProg --foo2 FOO2
etc
```

That usage line was created based on information in the `parser`.  So in theory one could write a function that takes the same information and generates lines such as I did.  But no, there isn't any such function in `argparse`.  And as far as I known, not in any of the parser packages that come standard with Python.

Why do you need this display?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just needed it in order to view all the outputs for all the possible commands, I thought that maybe there was a built in method which allowed you to list all the commands. But you are right, I can easily create a function that does that myself :).

Answer (score 0):

```
parser.print_help()
```

python args parse show available commands

python parse args man page

custom arg parse help show options

```
parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='store_true')

if arguments.help is True:
    print(parser.print_help())
    sys.exit()
```